# Amadeus_Login_automation[Web scraping]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am a little new to selenium but wanted to build a small **scraper** which will automatically login to Amadeus website and put some command and **scrape** the response.

My problem is I am not able to locate the login field in the login page. I have written multiple X_path for the login field and chrome is able to identify the same while testing but when I am putting the same X-path in the code, browser is giving --- no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@id='w1_dutyCode']//input[@type='text']"}

[This Xpath is matching in the chrome but still giving error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDnbz.png)

Guys, please help me, you can go through the login link and it would be highly appreciated if you can share the X_path which will enter the login details,

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep 
   


# create webdriver object 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Work\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')   

#Opening the Amadeus
driver.get("https://www.sellingplatformconnect.amadeus.com/LoginService/login.jsp?SITE=LOGINURL&LANGUAGE=GB")
driver.maximize_window()

#logging in 

sleep(2)

#creating element for user name 
[enter image description here][2]
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='w1_firstInput']//input[@type='text']").send_keys("USER_NAME")

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@id='w1_dutyCode']//input[@type='text']"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid locator:

```
//span[@id='w1_firstInput']//input[@type='text']
```

The correct locator using css selector with this value:

```
span#w2_firstInput input
```

And put wait. `sleep(2)` is bad way, use `WebDriverWait` like bellow:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
   


# create webdriver object 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Work\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')   

#Opening the Amadeus
driver.get("https://www.sellingplatformconnect.amadeus.com/LoginService/login.jsp?SITE=LOGINURL&LANGUAGE=GB")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span#w2_firstInput input')))
element.send_keys('username')

#office_id
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span#w2_officeId input').send_keys('office_id')

#password
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span#w2_passwordInput input').send_keys('password')

#login
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.button.confirm button').click()
```